# How can I have spell check for one language *but NOT* for another in El Capitain?

Tags: macos, spellcheck

I want to have spell checking ON for Greek (or any other language you have) and OFF for English.

At the System Preferences (Keyboard -> Text) I have enabled Greek *(where it says "Ελληνικά (iSquare)" in the images)* as the **ONLY** enabled language (I have disabled **all the others** from the pop-up menu (Set Up...) and I have choose it at the same menu.

[image: Set Up...]

[image: Greek Selected]

So Greek spell checking works.
But the problem is that when I type an **English** word, it spell checks that word too! (So if I type: "*helloo*" it changes it to "*hello*"!)

**This is what I want to avoid!**

Is there a way to have the checking done **only** in Greek and **not** in English?

So that "Εληνικά" will become "Ελληνικά", but "helloo" will stay "helloo".

Comment: This may be a bug connected with using a non-Apple spellcheck dictionary.

Comment: Maybe... but that does not help me... What can I do?

Comment: Nothing, as far as I know.  Are there any other Greek spellcheckers available to try?  Does the problem exist in all apps including TextEdit?

Comment: :-( ... (The same in all apps.)

Comment: Did you restart the programs/whole system after changing the spellcheck settings?

Comment: Have you also gone in the individual apps and checked Edit > Spelling and Grammar > Show Spelling and Grammar to make sure the dictionary is set to Greek and not to "automatic"?

Comment: It appears that English is always active when the overall system language is set to English. If you change the system language to Greek, the spell checker will stop checking English.

Comment: Pit: Yes. 

Tom Gewecke: Yes (otherwise it would not work anyway!)

Dictionarics Anonymous: I understand... But this is not what I want...

Answer (score 1):

The following script will set the spelling language to ONLY Korean and open a TextEdit window.

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin export PATH

CommandD()
{
osascript <<EndOfMyScript
tell application "System Events"
keystroke "d" using [command down, option down]
end tell
EndOfMyScript
}



currentDockHiddenState=$(defaults read com.apple.Dock autohide)
if [[ "$currentDockHiddenState" != "1" ]]; then
    CommandD
fi

# Disable text auto-replacement
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist NSAutomaticCapitalizationEnabled -bool false
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist NSAutomaticDashSubstitutionEnabled -bool false
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist NSAutomaticPeriodSubstitutionEnabled -bool false
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist NSAutomaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled -bool false
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist NSAutomaticSpellingCorrectionEnabled -bool false
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist NSAutomaticTextCompletionEnabled -bool false
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist NSSpellCheckerAutomaticallyIdentifiesLanguages -bool false
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist WebAutomaticSpellingCorrectionEnabled -bool false
defaults delete ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems -array
defaults delete ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist AppleLanguages
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist AppleLanguages -array-add "en" "ko"
defaults delete ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist NSLinguisticDataAssetsRequested
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist NSLinguisticDataAssetsRequested -array-add "en" "en_US" "ko"
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist NSPreferredSpellServerLanguage "ko"
defaults delete ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist NSPreferredSpellServerVendors
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist NSPreferredSpellServerVendors -dict "ko" -string "Apple"
defaults delete ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist NSPreferredSpellServers
defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist NSPreferredSpellServers -array-add "ko" "Apple"

osascript -e 'tell application "Finder"' -e 'set rrr to get bounds of window of desktop' -e 'end tell' -e 'tell application "TextEdit"' -e 'activate' -e 'set bounds of window 1 to rrr' -e 'end tell'
```